# Namespaces and packaging in C++

Tags: c++, architecture, namespaces, inversion-of-control, packaging

What is the best/cleanest way to use namespaces in packaged code?

E.g. in libraries like **boost** there seem to be very organized namespaces management, some techniques are used that allow to disambiguate names. The important thing, however, is that one won't see much code like

```
typedef namespace1::namespace2::sth_else::a_class<namespace3::namespace4::b_class> type;
```

usually, there's not much cross-namespacing, which indicates good architecture but also a good namespace management. The question is: what IS the good namespace management?

Say we have file structure like this:

```
component1/...  (depends on reusable_if)
component2/...  (depends directly on reusable_if and on component 1)
reusable/
reusable/some_part/
reusable/some_part/...
reusable/some_other_part/
reusable/some_other_part/...
reusable/SthThatUsesBothReusableParts.h   (implements reusable_if/ISth.h)
reusable/SthThatUsesBothReusableParts.cpp (implements reusable_if/ISth.h)
reusable_if/
reusable_if/ISth.h   (pure abstract class)
reusable_if/ISthElse.h (pure abstract class)
main.cpp (e.g. instantiates SthThatUsesBothReusableParts and passes to component1/2)
```

The reason why there is reusable_if/ folder is because both component1 and component2 want to reuse the same interfaces (hence none of them 'owns' the interfaces exclusively). Also, the assumption is that the project is indeed very big and needs proper namespaces for classes in each of the folders.

How would you apply namespaces in such a project?
Say I declare all classes in reusable/ in namespace `::reusable`. Should I put interfaces from reusable_if into namespace `::reusable` or into `::reusable_if`? Or maybe into none since it is used by component1 and component2?

What about namespaces in component1 and component2? Anything to remember?
What about keyword `using`? Let's say that I decide to add this `::reusable_if` namespace. Can I put `using reusable_if` into header files in component1 and component2, provided that `using ...` is placed inside namespace `::component1` and `::component2`?

I am open to any suggestions, also those not necessarily related to the above example.

Comment: In general keep namespace hierarchies as flat as possible.

Comment: @g-makulik but not any flatter than necessary to avoid name clashes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I use for my projects. My main rule is that each directory is a namespace and each file is a class, with very few exceptions (sometimes I group helper functions in subdirectories of a namespace `detail`, but without another nested namespace).

1. Keep your entire project inside a single top-level namespace named after your project.
2. Keep each utility component inside the top-level namespace, but in a separate directory. This is the only time I don't let my namespaces overlap with my directory tree.
3. Keep each independently releasable component within your project inside a nested namespace named after your component. For convenience, provide a single header named after your component and containing your entire component interface either in the directory corresponding to your namespace or directly at the top-level directory of your project.
4. Keep the implementation of each component inside a nested namespace `detail`. Contrary to classes, namespace do not have language support for `private` members, but the convention in Boost is that namespace `detail` should not directly be called by user-code.

No further nesting than `project::component::detail::function()` or `project:::component::class.member()` is required. If you provide complete interfaces that facilitate ADL, you can reuse your component functions inside your project as `function(x)` for a variable `x` of type `project::component::class` without worrying about name clashes.

Note that in Uncle Bob's language: "**the unit of reuse is the unit of release**". Each component should provide a bunch of coherent and mutually dependent classes and functions. In particular, it should provide a **complete interface** for that component. The C++ language will support this through **argument-dependent-lookup** (ADL). See this old column "[Namespaces and the Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm)" by Herb Sutter.

The presence of `reuse_if` and the presence of both `component` and `reusable` might be a code smell, unless the considerations that you mentioned in the comments actually apply. A component should be the unit of release. If you could independently reuse a piece of code, make it a separate component. If the code depends on another piece, release it together with that other code. See Sutter's column for these dependency relations.

Comment: Very useful answer, it aims exactly at what I wanted to know. However, regarding your remark about reusable_if: I don't agree - I cannot release "reusable" nor its interfaces together with component1 because component2 wants to use it as well. I did exactly what you suggested - I identified a reused (between component1 and component2) piece of code (the interfaces that reusable implements) and made it a separate component (reusable_if).

Comment: @Andrew Then it's probably not a smell, but it's good to make those dependency considerations explicit in your documentation!

Comment: In this case - would you put interfaces in reusable_if into any namespace or none (also having ADL in mind)?

Comment: @Andrew probably in a single namespace but in different headers so that clients can only include what they actually depend on. See also this old [column](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) by Scott Meyers.

Answer (score 6):

**Personal opinion disclaimer.** Your question basically asks for subjective answers, and will probably be closed for it, but I'll give it a shot.

---

Namespaces are primarily useful to avoid identifier clashes. There is "your" namespace (`mylib::`), and the namespaces of everybody else (`std::`, `boost::`, `icu::`, ...), and that is about as far as namespaces should be taken.

There is little benefit to be had by subdividing your project (as in, "your team's project") into sub-namespaces, *unless* you get a problem with identifier clashes -- in which case you should reconsider your strategy of calling your classes `X` and `Y`. ;-)

Things are a bit different in *huge* libs, like Boost. They effectively consist of many different projects, maintained by seperate teams, so there's a problem of project-specific identifiers clashing with each other if they were all lumped into `boost::` (and the clash possibly not showing up in casual testing).

If you stop looking at `boost::filesystem` as a "sub-namespace", and instead look at `boost::` as an "identity wrapper" for the individual projects `filesystem::`, `thread::`, `program_options::` and whatnot, so that they look more "Boost-ish", the picture becomes clearer.

Comment: Good points. I sometimes use namespaces to remove a part of a name. That is, instead of having a typedef `xyz::abcde_callback_type` I usually write my code to have `xyz::callback::abcde_type`. Do you consider that a bad practice?

Comment: @utnapistim: Hm... difficult question without having the context. The name might be used without the namespace alongside it (`using namespace xyz::callback;`). Would it still be expressive then? I readily accept longer typenames if it gives me crucial type information where it might needed, i.e. at the point of use (as opposed to "hidden somewhere else in the source"). Due to this, I consider `typedef` to be bad practice, with the sole exceptions of portability type wrapping and function pointers.

Comment: I think it would be (~expressive when `using namespace xyz::callback`). Consider the similar case in the lambda implementation of std library: you have `_1`, `_2`,  ... `_??` for unbound parameters binding and you can write `using namespace std::placeholders;` without loosing (much) readability.